# How does Steve Rogers treat Tony Stark post Civil War?

Tags: comics, marvel, iron-man, captain-america

I have a question about the aftermath of the [*Civil War*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_War_%28comics%29) crossover story-lines in [Marvel Comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Comics).

I have been out of the loop for a long time and my Google Fu has failed me! Please Sci-Fi, you are my only hope!

Now that Steve Rogers (Captain America) is among the living again, has he had an encounter with Tony Stark (Iron Man) yet? And if so how did it go? Are they still friends, or are they not talking to each other anymore because of what happened in Civil War?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are still friends. Read Avengers: Prime, it is a five issue miniseries set just after the "Siege" event that's about Cap, Thor and Iron Man. Cap and Iron Man are working together in the current Avengers storyline featuring the Infinity Gems.

Steve Rogers is the world's "Top Cop" - pretty much Nick Fury's old job. Steve has more reasons to mistrust Iron Man, but

> Tony Stark had his memory of last few years erased, so he doesn't remember what happened/isn't the same "douchey" Tony Stark. It was a way of undoing the last few years of everyone hating Tony and resetting him somewhat.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ugh, that last bit sounds like another terrible Marvel retcon.

Comment: @BilltheLizard It was a pretty fantastic arc in the Invincible Iron Man by Matt Fraction.  I highly recommend it, if you're into superhero comics.

Comment: @Keen: I am a big fan, but I haven't read very much since Civil War.  I didn't even realize there was a new Iron Man series until now.  I'll check it out.

Comment: @ Bill the Lizard while I agree retconning it was a bad idea and pretty much erased the meaning of the last few years, the execution was handled very well by Matt Fraction and is a good read.

Comment: I hate retcons. But Matt Fraction's run sounds interesting. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Keen: Great recommendation!  I got The Invincible Iron Man Omnibus and I can barely put it down.  Thank you.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Happy to spread the fandom. :)

Comment: Damn you all!  You'll get me to read Iron Man again... okay, probably not, too strapped for cash, but it'll go one the list (and Tony totally going with the establishment is so not-Tony, that I for one am happy about this retcon)